# Delete PDAs and return all lamport

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, sol, lamports

I was looking at the previous posts in this same forum and I think there are some caveats to be made on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [close method of Anchor](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html)

```
#[account(mut, close = receiver)]
pub data_account: Account<'info, MyData>,
#[account(mut)]
pub receiver: SystemAccount<'info>
```

Only the account space is removed and the lamports remained in the account.

The way in which I currently solved this problem is by sending the lamports to the initializer account before deleting the account, which remains at 0 (is 890880 lamports). The occupied space is 1213 (9333360 lamports). I share how the final function turned out.

```
use anchor_lang::{
prelude::*,
solana_program::system_instruction,
solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey,
}; 
use crate::state::accounts::*;
use crate::errors::ErrorCode;

pub fn delete(
        ctx: Context<Delete>
    ) -> Result<()> {
        require!(ctx.accounts.user.key() == ctx.accounts.x.pubkey.key(), ErrorCode::PubkeyError);
        let lamport: u64 = 9333360 - 890880;
        **ctx.accounts.x.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= lamport;
        **ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += lamport;
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Delete<'info> {
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"Account"], bump = main_account.bump_original)]
    pub main_account: Account<'info, MainAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut, 
        seeds = [x.seed.to_be_bytes().as_ref()], 
        bump = x.bump_original,
        close = user
    )]
    pub x: Account<'info, Sell>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub user: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

If anyone has another way to perform this procedure, I would appreciate your comment. Greetings.

Comment: Is this a bug or is this the way it has to be done? I believed the first way is supposed return all lamports.